# Reference for a derivative formula for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, tag-removed, matrices

I found the identity

$$ \frac{\partial( \det (X^T A X ))}{\partial X} = 2\det(X^TAX)AX(X^TAX)^{-1} $$

On the matrix cookbook (http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf).  It is equation 47 on p. 8.  Note that $X$ is an $n \times m$ matrix and $A$ is a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix.

I could not find the identity in their cited references...does anyone know of a textbook or paper that has this identity?

Comment: I don't understand the formula. On the one hand, the left-hand side should be linear form in $n^2$ variables, the differential of a scalar function with respect to $X$. On the other hand, the right-hand side is just a scalar. Both may not be equal.

Comment: I clarified what $X$ and $A$ are, that might help.

Comment: chain rule; i think the question is better suited to math.SE and will receive more attention there.

Comment: @Suvrit, easier said than done about the chain rule...I have tried this before:  I have the identity (from a textbook) $D_x det(x) = det(x)x^{-T}$ and the Frechet derivative of $X^TAX$ is $D_x (X^T A X)h = x^TAh + h^TAX$.  I find it hard to put the two together, especially because the Frechet derivative defintion of $x --- > det(x)$ involve a n inner product of matrices...

Comment: The question was answered on Math.se :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188456/reference-for-a-derivative-formula-for-matrices#comment434974_188456

Thanks for the tip Suvrit!

Comment: Great to know that you found a quick answer on m.se :-)

Comment: What does the derivative with respect to a matrix even mean? We're in a noncommutative ring here, so there might even be two distinct notions of a difference quotient...

Answer (score 1):

Some books to look for such things:

A M Mathai: "Jacobians of matrix transformations and functions nof matrix argument"

Magnus, Neudecker:  "Matrix Differential Calculus  with Applications in Statistics  and Econometrics"

Kollo, von Rosen: "Advanced Multivariate Statistics with Matrices"

Comment: Thank you but a short proof was recently given on Math.se: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188456/reference-for-a-derivative-formula-for-matrices#comment434974_188456